# How to fix Vue installation error on a Laravel Information

Tags: laravel, vue.js

### [enter image description here][1]    I wanted to install Vue for frontend scaffolding in Laravel and i got this error. Please how do I fix it?

> ```
> npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
>     npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
>
>     > node-sass@4.11.0 install C:\Users\AGZ\Desktop\LaravelSite\node_modules\node-sass
>     > node scripts/install.js
>
>     internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605
>         throw err;
>         ^
>
>     Error: Cannot find module 'psl'
>         at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:603:15)
>         at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:25)
>         at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:659:17)
>         at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
>         at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AGZ\Desktop\LaravelSite\node_modules\tough-cookie\lib\pubsuffix-psl.js:32:11)
>         at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:30)
>         at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:10)
>         at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
>         at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
>         at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
>     npm WARN img-loader@3.0.1 requires a peer of imagemin@^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies
> ```
>
> yourself.
>           npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.3.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>           npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
>           npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"}
>   (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> ```
>     npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>     npm ERR! errno 1
>     npm ERR! node-sass@4.11.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
>     npm ERR! Exit status 1
>     npm ERR!
>     npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.11.0 install script.
>     npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
>     npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>     npm ERR!     C:\Users\AGZ\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-30T19_50_15_978Z-debug.log
> ```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXxHZ.jpg**strong text**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing the package the error is throwing?

```
npm install ajv
```